# Find the set of all cluster points

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, limits

Given the set $A=[a,b)$ with $a < b$, write the set of all cluster points of $A$.

Because it states $a < b$, I'm not sure how to start the question.

Are $a$ and $b$ still both cluster points?

For $b$ you can get $I=[b-e,b+e]$ with $e>0$ where we can find a point $y$ such that $b-e < y < b < b+e$ and $y>a$ then $y$ is an element of $A$ and $y$ doesn't equal $b$ so $b$ is a cluster point.

(I think the above is correct proof although I am new to cluster points)
But then for a, im not sure on how to prove it. thanks

Comment: $a$ and $b$ are both cluster points, but check your exact definition of cluster point, it may also include the points in the interior.

Comment: how do you prove the interior are cluster points? thanks

Comment: The same way, any inverval $(c-\epsilon,c+\epsilon)$ will intersect $A-\{c\}$.  But the definition varies from author to author.  What is the exact definition of cluster point in your book?

Comment: it says "Given a set A and a point x, we say that x is a cluster point for the set A if in any open interval I containing x there are infinitely many points of A. Intervals are in the form I=(x-ϵ,x+ϵ) for ϵ>0"

Comment: Got it, so in that case the interior points are also cluster points.  It should be pretty clear why.  You just need to show if $c\in[a,b)$ then $(c-\varepsilon,c+\varepsilon)\cap[a,b)$ has infinitely many points.

Answer (score -1):

Given $\epsilon>0$ (and $\epsilon < b-a$), just take the mid-point between $a$ and $a+\epsilon$. This proves that $a$ is a cluster point of $A$. Now you should prove, with similar arguments, that every interior point of $A$ is also a cluster point, so that the closure of $A$ is $[a,b]$.

Of course $a<b$, otherwise $A=\emptyset$.